# How to create a image pointer line graph in android?

Tags: java, android, graph

[image]

Can any one help me to create a line graph like the image in android.

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: I have gone through some apis like achartengine,AndroidPlot but could not find a graph with pointer

Answer (score 2):

Using AChartEngine you can add an image, after making slight modifications in the AchartEngine - XYMultipleSeriesRenderer class. Along with X Axis text labels, Y axis text labels, add a custom property to supply your Bitmap.

```
 /** The X axis text labels. */
  private Map<Double, String> mXTextLabels = new HashMap<Double, String>();
  /** The Bitmap corresponding to event. */
  public Map<Double, Bitmap> mEventBitmaps = new HashMap<Double, Bitmap>();
```

Then in the draw method of your required chart, you can retrieve your corresponding bitmap from seriesRenderer ..

```
 private void drawBar(Canvas canvas, float xMin, float yMin, float xMax, float yMax, int scale,
      int seriesIndex, Paint paint, double barIndex) {
    SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = mRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(seriesIndex);
.......
.......
Bitmap eventflag = mRenderer.getEventBitmap(barIndex);
double offset = Math.round(xMax) - Math.round(xMin) - eventflag.getWidth();
canvas.drawBitmap(eventflag, Math.round(xMin) + (int) offset / 2, Math.round(yMin)
              - (2*eventflag.getHeight()), paint);
```

You will have to get familiarized with the XYMultipleSeriesRenderer in AchartEngine before diving deep into this.

Finally, in your project class(activity/fragment) from where you are displaying the chart, you can supply bitmaps for each point in the graph like this.

```
public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getBarRenderer() {

        if(list == null || list.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }

        // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        /*multiRenderer.setYLabels(0);*/
        for(int i=0; i< list.size();i++){
            ReportsList ma = list.get(i);
            multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, ma.getMinutes());  
            multiRenderer.addBarColor(i, "#" + ma.getColor()); 
            String eventType = ma.getEvent();
            int drawableId = getEventBitMap(eventType);
            if(drawableId != -1){
                multiRenderer.addEventBitmap(i, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId));

            }

        }
```

Comment: I'm using AchartEngine Jar file. How to achieve the solution, you mentioned?